# Prepopulate Rails Mailer Message with existing template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a mailer set up so when the user hits a "Submit Mail" button, the template associated with that action is sent to the appropriate people.  What I would like to do is first allow them to edit the email before it is sent.  I have a modal set up to pop up an email form, but I would like the "message" text_area to prepopulate with the mailer template.

This is the show page with my submit button:

```
...
...
<% if user_in_engineering? %>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#submitModal">
  Submit for Approval
  </button>
  <%= button_to "Close ECN", {action: "close", :id => @ecn.id}, :onclick => "return confirm('Once an ECN is closed it can no longer be edited, are you sure you want to close this ECN?')" %>
  <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_ecn_path(@ecn) %>
<% end %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', ecns_path %>



<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="submitModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit ECN Approval Email</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <%= render 'submit_email_fields' %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <%= button_to "Submit for Approval", {action: "submit", :id => @ecn.id}, type: "button", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The Modal renders this page:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'submit' %>
<p><label for="email_subject">Subject</label>
<%= text_field 'email', 'subject' %></p>
<p><label for="email_recipient">Recipients</label>
<%= text_field 'email', 'recipient' %></p>
<p><label for="email_message">Message</label><br/>
<%= text_area 'email', 'message', value: @message %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Send" %>
<%= form_tag %>
```

I've got a template called submitted.text.erb that is in my mailer view folder, and what I would like is for that text to appear in the message text area of the modal, then I think I can handle routing the parameters around.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an old question, but I was running to this issue, I hacked around it this manner.

In my controller 
   @message = Mailer.method(variable).body

In my view
   <%= text_area 'email', 'message', value: @message %>